# How do I integrate an existing modal framework written in JQuery in angular?

Tags: jquery, angularjs

We have purchased some CSS for a whole bunch of our UI. It includes things like tabs, wizards and modals. The template often uses JQuery to do the rendering. All the help I have read about angular discourages JQuery and we should try to do it in angular. Unfortunately this is a 3rd party tool and our team is sold on it.

We have a good number of screens where we display a grid. The page includes one 'Add New' button and an 'Edit' button for each row displayed on the grid. When the user clicks the 'Add New' button we need to show a modal that allows him to capture the new entity (whatever it is). When the user clicks 'Edit' it opens a similar modal and populates the fields.

The modal needs to be opened with some JQuery calls to his plugin. Would I be able to use JQuery with angular in the controllers just so that I can open the theme's modal. **I will only JQuery for that.** For the rest I will stick to the angular way as far as possible.

Comment: No one stops you from using jquery anywhere :) even if it can have side effects due DOM manipulation carried out by AngularJS and jquery simultaneously :) . Understand directives and they would act as bridge between your jquery and angular model.

Answer (score 2):

First of all, it is not forbidden to use jQuery with AngularJS. It is highly recommended that you use it as carefully as possible because you will lose some of it's data-bind and events power that you don't usually need to code.

When you are using a 3rd-party, you have three choices.

1. You can use a bridge that already exists like the one for Bootstrap: (http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/)
2. You can build a bridge for what you need between your 3rd-party plugin and AngularJS using directives, watch, events and making sure to call `scope.$apply()` where it is appropriate. As an example:

   `<div data-modal title="Header">Content</div>`

   Can automatically create your modal by calling `$(element).modal()` and apply a template to the HTML if you want to simplify.
3. You can stop giving a damn and call `scope.$apply()` when you need when you are using your 3rd-party. This is probably not the best solution for you and bad long term, but if you don't have time to write the bridge or you will never reuse it, it's not the end of the world.

The third option is always there, but don't use it unless you have no choice. Developping a simple directive and adding features is the best way to go unless something solid has already been coded. And when you get used to it, it's quite fankly easy.

Comment: I thought that writing my own directive might be the way to go. I will give it a shot. Thanks

Comment: Maybe some day we will have a way to interact with jQuery plugins without having to create your own directive. A directive that can read jQuery plugins and just do it. That would be a game changer for AngularJS because jQuery plugins are abundants and AngularJS is still very young.

Answer (score 1):

In angular UI they have given provision for that you can check (jQuery Passthrough - Call the jQuery function or plugin specified on the element) @ http://angular-ui.github.io/ui-utils/

In that they have showed how to call the bootstrap tooltip with almost no work

Comment: This works nicely if there aren't a lot of additional parameters which unfortunately is not our case. Our case requires quite a bit including specifying buttons and callbacks.

Answer (score 0):

write your custom directive, sent in directive scope with data for each row
and in your directive call jQuery functions.

I use this way in real project

**UPD**

```
'use strict';

angular.module('yourApp')
.directive('directiveName', function ($parse) {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        scope: { params: '=' },
        template: '<div></div>',
        replace: true,
        transclude: true,
        link: function ($scope, element, attrs) {

            var model = $scope.params,
                options = model.getData(),
                out;

            var ms = element.magicSuggest({       //I use jQuery function magicSuggest
                //some params for jQuery function
            });

            $(ms).on('selectionchange', function (event, combo, selection) {
                //use events with my element
            });

        }
    }
});
```

Comment: You don't have an example of this?